# Is there a solution to plot 3D multiple time line series in web application using highcharts or any other libraries

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I am trying to plot 3D .NET web charts to show time vs temperature lines with the Z Axis showing the curve for each months. I am looking for a solution which is Similar to the one shown on the images below.

[image: 3D multi axis line chart]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it by using the `scatter3d` series in Highcharts. Because I am not a .NET developer I prepared a basic demo in Highcharts JS how to achieve similar chart.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r1Lant7p/

```
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'scatter3d',
    options3d: {
      enabled: true,
      alpha: 10,
      beta: 30,
      depth: 250,
      viewDistance: 5,
      fitToPlot: false,
    }
  },
```

And here is a basic demo of the `scatter3d` chart in the Highcharts.NET wrapper: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo/Gallery?demo=Scatter3d&theme=default

API: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/index.html

Comment: Here's a demo with three temperature series: https://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/8cn542h6/

Comment: I tried both your options in .NET but the chart was not displaying

Comment: @tonyrox could you share your config? I will send it to check to our .NET developer.